# Postgres select statement returns no rows on the cli

Tags: postgresql

I have a [test database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database/tree/master/ChinookDatabase/DataSources) with some rows in it that I am trying to do a select on.

If I run this statement in an IDE like DataGrip I get back rows:

### command:

```
SELECT * FROM public."Album";
```

### output:

```
1,For Those About To Rock We Salute You
2,Balls to the Wall
3,Restless and Wild
4,Let There Be Rock
5,Big Ones
6,Jagged Little Pill
7,Facelift
8,Warner 25 Anos
9,Plays Metallica By Four Cellos
10,Audioslave
```

I'm trying to do the same thing on the psql command line and it's not working.

I connect to the database and to a select on the table it returns nothing:

```
\c our_db
our_db=# SELECT * FROM "Album"
```

If I use a semi colon I get an error:

```
our_db-# SELECT * FROM "Album";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM "Album";
```

I am new to postgres. I'm on version `12.3`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you didn't enter a semicolon after the first `select` statement, but entered another, psql interpreted the query as `select * from Album select * from Album;`.  After entering the first line without the semicolon, psql assumed you weren't done yet.  Had you entered a semicolon at that point, your results would have been displayed.

Comment: To add to Bill's comment, the prompt change (from our_db=#  to our_db-#) indicates that it thinks you are entering a multi line statement

Comment: OK thanks. When I put a semicolon after each command, I get back an error that says: `ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"`. How do I get past this?

Comment: Oh, I had to set `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';` and then I was able to get rows back on the command line. Thanks for your help guys! If you put your advice into an answer I will accept it.